# Slow SQL taking almost 1s to execute with only 24000 records! (EXPLAIN included)

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, mysql-5.7, explain

Any ideas how to improve and what the actual culprit is?

records in product are only 24000

takes 0.85s to run

Mysql 5.7

```sql
select `product`.* from `product` 
 inner join `manufacturer` on `product`.`manufacturer_id` = `manufacturer`.`id` 
 left join `manufacturer_bundle` on `manufacturer_bundle`.`id` =  `manufacturer`.`manufacturer_bundle_id` 
 left join `color` on `product`.`color_id` = `color`.`id` 
 left join `product_code_upc` on `product`.`product_code` = `product_code_upc`.`product_code` 
 inner join `supplier` on `supplier`.`id` = `product`.`supplier_id` 
 left join `color_code` on `product`.`color_code_id` = `color_code`.`id` and `manufacturer`.`id` = `color_code`.`manufacturer_id` 
where `product`.`available` > 0 and `product`.`is_bought_copy` is null 
  and `product`.`deleted_at` is null 
order by case
 when `product`.`product_code` LIKE "QR-0012-ft" then  1
 when `product`.`product_code` LIKE "QR-0012-gt" then 2
 when `product`.`product_code` LIKE "QR-0012-at" then  3
 when `product`.`product_code` LIKE "QR-0012-xt" then 4
 when `product`.`product_code` LIKE "QR-0012-ut" then  5
 when `product`.`product_code` LIKE "QA-0012-ft" then 6
 when `product`.`product_code` LIKE "QQ-0012-ft" then  7
 else 11 end, 
 `supplier`.`state` desc, 
 `product`.`product_code` desc, 
 `manufacturer`.`name` desc 
limit 15 offset 0
```

The explain:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | partitions | type        | possible_keys                                                                                                                         | key                                                   | key_len | ref                                              | rows | filtered | Extra                                                                                                                |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | product             | NULL       | index_merge | product_is_bought_copy_index,product_manufacturer_id_index,product_available_index,product_supplier_id_index,product_deleted_at_index | product_is_bought_copy_index,product_deleted_at_index | 2,5     | NULL                                             | 6431 |    50.00 | Using intersect(product_is_bought_copy_index,product_deleted_at_index); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | manufacturer        | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                                               | 8       | plum_laravel.product.manufacturer_id             |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                                                                                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | manufacturer_bundle | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                                               | 4       | plum_laravel.manufacturer.manufacturer_bundle_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                                                                                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | color               | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                                               | 8       | plum_laravel.product.color_id                    |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                                                                                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | product_code_upc    | NULL       | ref         | product_code_upc_product_code_index                                                                                                   | product_code_upc_product_code_index                   | 767     | plum_laravel.product.product_code                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                                                                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | supplier            | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                                               | 8       | plum_laravel.product.supplier_id                 |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                                                                                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | color_code          | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,color_code_manufacturer_id_index                                                                                              | PRIMARY                                               | 4       | plum_laravel.product.color_code_id               |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                                                                                          |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

As requested the SHOW CREATE TABLEs:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `color_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `upc_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `available` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_product_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_condition_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_order_history` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color_code_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_bought_copy` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bought_product_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_uuid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_product_code_index` (`product_code`),
  KEY `product_color_code_id_index` (`color_code_id`),
  KEY `product_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `product_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`),
  KEY `product_is_bought_copy_index` (`is_bought_copy`),
  KEY `product_bought_product_id_index` (`bought_product_id`),
  KEY `product_description_uuid_index` (`description_uuid`),
  KEY `product_price_index` (`price`),
  KEY `product_upc_code_index` (`upc_code`),
  KEY `product_description_index` (`description`),
  KEY `product_color_id_index` (`color_id`),
  KEY `product_manufacturer_id_index` (`manufacturer_id`),
  KEY `product_state_index` (`state`),
  KEY `product_product_condition_id_index` (`product_condition_id`),
  KEY `product_available_index` (`available`),
  KEY `product_supplier_id_index` (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `product_supplier_product_code_index` (`supplier_product_code`),
  KEY `product_deleted_at_index` (`deleted_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=681005 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 


CREATE TABLE `manufacturer` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_bundle_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `manufacturer_name_index` (`name`),
  KEY `manufacturer_manufacturer_bundle_id_index` (`manufacturer_bundle_id`),
  KEY `manufacturer_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `manufacturer_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=306 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |



CREATE TABLE `manufacturer_bundle` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `manufacturer_bundle_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `manufacturer_bundle_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=226 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |



CREATE TABLE `color` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `color_bundle_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `color_name_index` (`name`),
  KEY `color_color_bundle_id_index` (`color_bundle_id`),
  KEY `color_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `color_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3256 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |



CREATE TABLE `product_code_upc` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manufacturer_bundle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_code_nospecial` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `upc_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_code_upc_manufacturer_bundle_id_index` (`manufacturer_bundle_id`),
  KEY `product_code_upc_product_code_index` (`product_code`),
  KEY `product_code_upc_product_code_nospecial_index` (`product_code_nospecial`),
  KEY `product_code_upc_upc_code_index` (`upc_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci



CREATE TABLE `supplier` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `plum_account_nr` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `wantsheet_supplier_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountant_supplier_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `inventory_listing` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `supplier_plum_account_nr_index` (`plum_account_nr`),
  KEY `supplier_company_name_index` (`company_name`),
  KEY `supplier_firstname_index` (`firstname`),
  KEY `supplier_lastname_index` (`lastname`),
  KEY `supplier_position_index` (`position`),
  KEY `supplier_address1_index` (`address1`),
  KEY `supplier_address2_index` (`address2`),
  KEY `supplier_city_index` (`city`),
  KEY `supplier_zip_index` (`zip`),
  KEY `supplier_state_index` (`state`),
  KEY `supplier_wantsheet_supplier_id_index` (`wantsheet_supplier_id`),
  KEY `supplier_accountant_supplier_id_index` (`accountant_supplier_id`),
  KEY `supplier_type_index` (`type`),
  KEY `supplier_inventory_listing_index` (`inventory_listing`),
  KEY `supplier_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `supplier_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=595 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 



CREATE TABLE `color_code` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_bundle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `color_code_code_index` (`code`),
  KEY `color_code_manufacturer_id_index` (`manufacturer_id`),
  KEY `color_code_color_bundle_id_index` (`color_bundle_id`),
  KEY `color_code_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `color_code_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2095 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE xyz\G` for all the tables in your query. Please do not upload images for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) - use text instead...

Comment: How much time do you think the query should take, and why?

Comment: @mustaccio well, I was hoping it would take A LOT less time especially since it's only a few rows. Why? well I'm the one asking. Not sure why you are asking me? seems a bit passive aggressive to me. You ok my dude?

Comment: @Vérace I added explain in text and show create as well, hope it is helpful somehow

Comment: For one, you probably shouldn't be joining the tables that are not used in obtaining the result; you really need only three.

Comment: and use combined indexes, and reduce the number which aren't useful

Answer (score 2):

`Using intersect` almost always means that you should add a composite index.

```
where `product`.`available` > 0
  and `product`.`is_bought_copy` is null 
  and `product`.`deleted_at` is null
```

needs

```
INDEX(is_bought_copy, deleted_at,   -- in either order, first since "="
      available)                    -- last, since "range"
```

That index will help some, but probably not a lot.

The `ORDER BY` cannot be optimized, nor helped by an index.  So must find all the possible rows, sort them, then finally deliver the first 15.

Shrinking the `(255)` to realistic limits might help some.  (It might avoid an on-disk temp table.)  Also, if you don't need all the columns of `product`, specify only the columns needed.

**Also**

- Get rid of the `JOINs` that don't lead to anything, such as `color` and `color_code`.
- Some columns seem redundant -- color & color_code; description and description_uuid.
- Get rid of `created_at` and/or `updated_at` unless you actually use them.
- Get rid of any indexes on flags; they are unlikely to be useful.

Comment: uff, love it... you are right! didn't even notice the joins that lead to nothing... I see the `order by` is the culprit though. That is why I somehow would love materialized views... is there a different way to side step the order by problem? like that the select naturally returns everything in the right order off the bat? I can as well cache on the application layer I guess

Comment: @Toskan - It should be possible to avoid that `CASE` in MySQL 8.0 (cf "generated column"), but there are still 3 tables involved in the `ORDER BY`.  That prevents using any index to avoid having a big sort before getting to the `LIMIT`.

Comment: understood. Isn't there a way to create the primary key in a way that it spits out the results always in the order that I want (or something like that)? problem is, it's hacky eh. I will probably just stick to caching...